# React - use Link to and pass data to new component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I currently have a react page that displays a List of orders for the user that is logged in (see UserWelcome below) this page works as I want it to. I now want to make the list of order numbers found in the map / list, clickable and load a new page (OrderDetails as seen below). But I don't know how to pass the OrderNumber from the map to the OrderDetails page so I can use it in my api search. Can anybody tell me how this is done please?

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class UserWelcome extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: false,
          };
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        const serachByUserId = this.props.location.state;

        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = "my web api" + serachByUserId;
        fetch(proxyurl + url) 
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false }));

    };
    
    render() {
        const { data,  isLoading } = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading ...</p>;
          };

        if (data.length === 0){
            return <p> no data found</p>
        }

        console.log('data =', data)

        return (
          <div>
            <p> UserID = {data.UserId}</p>
            <p> Welcome back {data.UserName}</p>
            <p> Below you can find a list of your Orders, link each order to view more details:</p>
            <ul>
            {data.orders.map(order=>
              <li><Link to={{ pathname: "/OderDetails"}}>Order number: {order.orderNumber}</Link></li>
            )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default UserWelcome;




import React from 'react';

class OrderDetails extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        const { data } = props.location
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
          };
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){

        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = "my wbi api url" + DATA PASSED INTO THE COMPONANT?;
        fetch(proxyurl + url) 
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false }));

    };
    
    render() {
        const { data,  isLoading } = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading ...</p>;
          };

        if (data.length === 0){
            return <p> no data found</p>
        }
    
        return (
          <ul>
            <p> Order Number XXX(from what has been passed in from other componant)</p>
            <p> then i will use this section to log the data from the web api</p>
          </ul>
        );
      }
}

export default OrderDetails;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass it through link and do it like:

```
 <li><Link to={{ pathname: "/OderDetails", state: {orderNumber: orderNumber}}>Order number: {order.orderNumber}</Link></li>
        )}
```

and access it on OrderDetaile component like:

```
props.location.state.orderNumber
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have just tried this but it says its is undefined when i have tried to display it in the console log, do you know how I would fix it sorry?

Comment: what did you console log? if you did `props.location.orderNumber` then try `this.props.location.orderNumber`

Comment: Ah ! sorry silly mistake, that has worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that

```js
{data.orders.map(({orderNumber}) =>
  <li><Link to={{ pathname: "/OderDetails", orderNumber}}>Order number: {orderNumber}</Link></li>
)}
```

And then

```js
this.props.location.orderNumber
```